# Deploying CherryPy (daemon)

Tags: python, deployment, cherrypy

I've followed the basic CherryPy tutorial (http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPyTutorial).  One thing not discussed is deployment.

How can I launch a CherryPy app as a daemon and "forget about it"?  What happens if the server reboots?

Is there a standard recipe?  Maybe something that will create a service script (/etc/init.d/cherrypy...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a [Daemonizer](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/process/plugins/daemonizer.html) plugin for CherryPy included by default which is useful for getting it to start but by far the easiest way for simple cases is to use the cherryd script:

```
> cherryd -h
Usage: cherryd [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c CONFIG, --config=CONFIG
                        specify config file(s)
  -d                    run the server as a daemon
  -e ENVIRONMENT, --environment=ENVIRONMENT
                        apply the given config environment
  -f                    start a fastcgi server instead of the default HTTP
                        server
  -s                    start a scgi server instead of the default HTTP server
  -i IMPORTS, --import=IMPORTS
                        specify modules to import
  -p PIDFILE, --pidfile=PIDFILE
                        store the process id in the given file
```

As far as an init.d script goes I think there are examples that can be Googled.

And the `cherryd` is found in your:

> virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/cherryd

or in: https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/default/cherrypy/cherryd

Answer (score 19):

Daemonizer can be pretty simple to use:

```
# this works for cherrypy 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 10.04
from cherrypy.process.plugins import Daemonizer
# before mounting anything
Daemonizer(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()

cherrypy.tree.mount(MyDaemonApp, "/")
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

[There is a decent HOWTO for SysV style here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto)

To summarize:

1. Create a file named for your application in `/etc/init.d` that calls `/bin/sh`

   `sudo vim /etc/init.d/MyDaemonApp`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh  
   echo "Invoking MyDaemonApp";  
   /path/to/MyDaemonApp  
   echo "Started MyDaemonApp. Tremble, Ye Mighty."
   ```
2. Make it executable

   `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/MyDaemonApp`
3. Run `update-rc.d` to create our proper links in the proper runtime dir.

   `sudo update-rc.d MyDaemonApp defaults 80`
4. `sudo /etc/init.d/MyDaemonApp`

Comment: I have no idea what a `spizouzou` is, but the variable is entirely unnecessary. Simply say: `Daemonizer(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()` and the plugin will persist because the `engine` now keeps a reference to it alive.

Comment: @brandon craig rhodes is correct. No need to create a variable.

Comment: http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/WindowsService As mentioned elsewhere, one can create a windows service with about the same amount of effort. Pay attention to the logging bits at the bottom of the page! They are important.

Comment: Changed to reflect @BrandonRhodes critique.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a tutorial/project skeleton, [cherrypy-webapp-skeleton](https://heptapod.host/saajns/cherrypy-webapp-skeleton), which goal was to fill the gaps for deploying a real-world CherryPy application on Debian* for a web-developer. It features extended `cherryd` for daemon privilege drop. There's also a number of important script and config  files for `init.d`, `nginx`, `monit`, `logrotate`. The tutorial part describes how to put things together and eventually *forget about it*. The skeleton part proposes a way of possible arrangement of CherryPy webapp project assets.

---

* It was written for Squeeze but practically it should be same for Wheezy.

Comment: The code in this tutorial was really helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Info on Daemonizer options**

When using Daemonizer, the [docs](http://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/deploy.html#run-as-a-daemon) don't state the options, e.g. how to redirect *stdout* or *stderr*. From the source of the [Daemonizer](http://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/_modules/cherrypy/process/plugins.html) class you can find the options. As a reference take this example from my project:

```
# run server as a daemon
d = Daemonizer(cherrypy.engine,
               stdout='/home/pi/Gate/log/gate_access.log',
               stderr='/home/pi/Gate/log/gate_error.log')
d.subscribe()
```