# Can a standalone web application built with cherrypy be compiled?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I want to build a web application that stands completely by itself, apache not required. Is cherrypy a good solution, and can this be compiled with something like py2exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a scripting language and is not usually compiled. What you are talking about is packaging your scripts into an exe (via p2exe), bundled with the relative modules and an interpreter.

This is possible with many scripts, including CherryPy, as p2exe basically sticks all your scripts together in one place, then executes it with the interpreter. [This link will allow you to build your application into an exe.](http://www.daniweb.com/code/post968427.html) I would however recommend that you use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead, as I have found it to be much easier.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463510/deploying-cherrypy-daemon) shows that you can daemonize CherryPy, and from the page of CherryPy ->

> Your CherryPy powered web applications
>   are in fact stand-alone Python
>   applications embedding their own
>   multi-threaded web server. You can
>   deploy them anywhere you can run
>   Python applications. Apache is not
>   required

So yes you can deploy CherryPy, self-contained without Apache. CherryPy seems to be a fine solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically describing [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/).