# How to shutdown CherryPy

Tags: cherrypy

I created the following function to shutdown `cherrypy`:

```
import cherrypy
cherrypy.engine.exit()
```

Name of the file: `shutdown.py`. And then I enter the command `python shutdown.py` in the command line. The following messages showed up:

```
[06/Sep/2014:11:28:22] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[06/Sep/2014:11:28:22] ENGINE HTTP Server None already shut down
[06/Sep/2014:11:28:22] ENGINE No thread running for None.
[06/Sep/2014:11:28:22] ENGINE No thread running for None.
[06/Sep/2014:11:28:22] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[06/Sep/2014:11:28:22] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[06/Sep/2014:11:28:22] ENGINE Bus EXITED
```

However, CherryPy is still running. How do I shutdown CherryPy then?

Also, what if I have multiple cherrypy servers running at the same time? Does the `shutdown.py` kill all of them?

Comment: Which OS are you running? You need to use signals to kill another process. There is no global cherrypy server.

Comment: OS: ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CherryPy application is contained in ordinary Python process. To treat CherryPy application like a server (e.g. mysql, nginx, etc. which you can `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`) you should deploy it accordingly.

For an ad-hoc case, just tell [cherryd](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html?#cherryd) to save *pid* file with `--pidfile` or integrate [`PIDFile plugin`](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/refman/process/plugins/pidfile.html#cherrypy.process.plugins.PIDFile) into your code directly. Then just `` kill `cat /path/to/pidfile` ``.

For a full-blown deployment read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467279/2072035).

Comment: Thanks, but I used the `server.py` to start cherrypy as provided by this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-applications-using-a-cherrypy-web-server-behind-nginx). How can obtain the process id of cherrypy?

Comment: I've already told you -- use PIDFile plugin. Something like ``plugins.PIDFile(engine, '/run/yourapp/yourapp.pid').subscribe()``. Take a look at [cherryd source](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/2a045705a5e403699aab915ab32ea8484f259fa1/cherrypy/cherryd?at=default#cl-39) for the context.

Answer (score 0):

This question is 6 years ago, but I want to answer something important. The best way to shutdown Cherrypy server is setting the following configuration in your code:

```
cherrypy.config.update({ 'server.shutdown_timeout': 1 })
```

Of this way you are sure the server is shutdown, you can see more about that in this [issue](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1527#issuecomment-264796869). So, I hope this can help someone.